# How can l display files from 1 to 17 and from 3605 to 3610 using ls?

Tags: command-line, files, ls

l would like to display files of the following format :

```
train_example_X.py
```

such that **X** varies from 1 to 9000.

**What l have tried ?**

```
ls train_example_[1-17].py
```

returns only
`train_example_1.py` and `train_example_7.py` however l'm supposed to get all the files from 1 to 17.

and for :

```
ls train_example_[3605-3610].py
```

it returns
`train_example_1.py` and `train_example_3.py`

What is wrong with my command ?

Comment: `[1-17]` matches the character range `1` to `1`, and the character `7`. Reread `man bash`, and use `train_example_{1..17}`

Answer (score 4):

Well, you're using `[...]` there, which is pathname expansion and that supports only ASCII ranges of 0-9 so you'd have to get creative with it or use extended globbing

Simpler (imho) approach would be to use brace expansion,

```
ls train_example_{1..17}.py train_example{3605..3610}.py
```

Comment: Nesting ftw! `ls train_example_{{1..17},{3605..3610}}.py`

Comment: Or even `ls train_example_{{1..17},36{05..10}}.py`…